# pivot table using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have data set having columns

```
Country  
2001    
2002    
2003
...


import python as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"country":['India','UK','France','US','Nepal'],'2001':[1,2,3,4,5],
               '2002':[1,2,3,4,5],'2003':[1,2,3,4,5],'2004':[1,2,3,4,5],
               '2005':[1,2,3,4,5],'2006':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I want to pivot this table with three columns

```
Country    
Year    
Value
```

How should I extend my python code for the output above?

Comment: `import python as pd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.melt(id_vars='country', var_name='Year')

   country  Year  value
0    India  2001      1
1       UK  2001      2
2   France  2001      3
3       US  2001      4
4    Nepal  2001      5
5    India  2002      1
6       UK  2002      2
7   France  2002      3
8       US  2002      4
9    Nepal  2002      5
10   India  2003      1
...
```